# Facebook Game White Screen, systematic across many games

Tags: facebook, screen

Some of my players who saw a White Screen while Facebook had our App turned off for an update we missed can not get the White Screen to go away now.  I've been searching and I find similar mentions of this White Screen on many other Facebook game support forums with no good answer.  Here is a comment from a customer I've put through the ringer trying to fix it.  I've seen identical comments on other games forums.  The main thing here to point out is that if he logs in with his wife's FB our game works fine, same computer/browser, everything.  This leads me to believe there is something Facebook is catching on their end.  The only thing I can think of now is for players effected by white screens is to delete and then reinstall the app.

"At this point the following has been done: Clear browser history. Cleared Flash cache. Enabled Secure browsing in FB. None of this solves the issue. But here's something interesting: I logged on with my friends account who had never played Slot Stories. The app loaded just fine. On my account however, nothing. And from past comments of other users, they did the same. I think you need to look into why If it will load from a new FB account on the SAME computer in the SAME browser, then the browser history, flash cache, and internet security settings have NOTHING to do with the problem!!"

If anyone has any insight on why our game would work from a different facebook account on the same computer please let me know.  Also, please let me know what to tell all my players to do, because we've tried everything!

Answer (score 0):

My users are reporting that deleting and reinstalling the Facebook apps works to fix the white screen.  Also, all of their coins/levels were saved.